# Position HTML Text to Start on the Right Hand Side

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a problem. I need to position the end of a text to the RIGHT HAND SIDE, and if the text value is changed/length is increased I want to push it to the left hand side. For example, let's say you have this:
[image]

Then imagine if the text Increases, I want it to remain in the sample place on the right hand side (the last letter), like this:
[image]

What I have currently:

```
<div style="position: absolute; float: right; bottom: 0; right: 150px; margin-bottom: 35px;">TECH: <strong>Test</strong></div>
```

If I increase the text (I'm using ASP.net, so the 'test' value will change), and dont adjust the right: positioning, it looks off.

Comment: I have to ask: absolute positioning is a poor way to outline a document. What is the reasoning behind this approach, versus, just a `<div>` with a CSS rule: `text-align: right`?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, the reason for this is because I need to stick it to the bottom, right above that Random Address Text. I couldn't use text-align right because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be understanding what you are asking exactly, but why wouldn't text-align: right; in CSS not work?

edit: here is a new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/65c00hfm/1/

```
    <div>
      <p>This goes above the address</p>
      <p>This is the address</p>
    </div>

div{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 20px;
}

p{
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: I need it stuck to the bottom, right above the Random Address text, I wasn't able to have it stuck to the bottom without using absolute positioning

Comment: any way you can create a fiddle so I can see what the issue is?